# marginpar alignment

Tags: pdftex, minipage, document-classes

I need to set some text from a my own class file, on the left-hand side margin of a document for that I use the marginpar,Also content in the extreme left side should not overlap the contents on the
right side of the margin, so it needs to be adjusted as per
requirement. Can you please advise me how to go about it?

The following code is my class file

```
\usepackage{geometry,marginnote}
\newgeometry{left=13.8pc,right=3.5pc,top=5.9pc,textwidth=170mm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,sectsty}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{authblk}
\def\Affilfont{\small\color{black}}
%usepackage{fancyhdr}
%pagestyle{fancy}
%cfoot{\ifnum\value{page} >1\newgeometry{left=19.8pc,right=3.5pc,top=5.9pc,textwidth=170mm}\thepage \else\fi}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \vspace*{-\topskip}    
  \begingroup\centering  
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \hrule height \z@ 
    {\LARGE \color{yellow}\@title\par}%
    \vskip 1.5em 
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        {\color{yellow}{\@author}}
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em 
    {\large \@date}%
  \par\endgroup     
  \vskip 1.5em
\reversemarginpar
\marginpar{
Name :Kevin
email:sample@gmail.com
Received:28 November2016 
Accepted: 4 December2016
}
}
\endinput
```

The tex code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\input /home/kevin/Desktop/script/tex/sample.cls
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Sample File}
\author[1]{Author A\thanks{A.A@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author B\thanks{B.B@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author C\thanks{C.C@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author D\thanks{D.D@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author E\thanks{E.E@university.edu}}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science, University}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering, University}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[3-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the code? And have you tried `\marginpar{<text to appear in the margins>}`?

Comment: You can't typeset anything in the class file, of course. You need to not typeset before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @jon I use the code \begin{minipage}some text \end{minipage}. now i use the code \marginpar but how align the content also it appeared in separate page please help

Comment: This question is more than unclear in its current state. The picture posted is just a [screent from the wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout).

Comment: Rule of thumb: Writing a class is for experienced users only. If you are new, read an introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: your question is completely unclear. You show an image of a table of contents which typically would be made by `\tableofcontents` but then ask a question about putting text in a margin (which would normally be `\marginpar` (but there doesn't seem to be any marginal text in the image) and something about `minipage` which does not seem to be related to the image at all. Please edit the question to have some tex code, and if it does the wrong thing, or gives an error, say what it does and what you want it to do,

Comment: What is going on? A class that is far apart from a class, the definition of a strange title. Do you want to submit to a journal? Ask the journal editor for a suitable template.

Comment: If `sample.cls` is a class file the syntax would be `\documentclass{sample}` not `\input /home/kevin/Desktop/script/tex/sample.cls`

Comment: You seem to have confused 'class' (`.cls`) files and 'style' (`.sty`) files. `\documentclass{article}` means you are loading `article.cls`. You should rename `sample.cls` to `sample.sty` and load it as a normal file (e.g., `\usepackage{sample}`).